# Weird behavior with the ObjectStateEntry's State

Tags: logging, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, objectcontext

I have the following extension method and I'm not sure why each entries state is being changed to Unchanged after I call `entry.AcceptChanges()` on one entry.

```
    public static void SaveWithLogging(this ObjectContext context)
    {
        IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> entries = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted);
        foreach (var entry in entries)
            CreateTransactionLog(context, entry);
    }


    private static void CreateTransactionLog(ObjectContext context, ObjectStateEntry entry)
    {
        using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {

            string operationType = entry.State.ToString();

            context.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added) entry.AcceptChanges();

            var columnNames = (from p in entry.EntitySet.ElementType.Members
                               select p.Name)
                               .ToList();

            Log log = new Log();
            log.CreateDate= DateTime.Now;
            log.UserName = "Test";
            log.Operation = operationType;
            context.AddObject("Logs", log);

            foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
            {
                string oldValue = entry.State == EntityState.Added ? string.Empty : entry.OriginalValues[columnName].ToString();
                string newValue = entry.CurrentValues[columnName].ToString();
                if (oldValue.CompareTo(newValue) != 0)
                {
                    // Create Log Details
                    LogDetail logDetails = LogDetail();
                    logDetails.LogId = log.LogId;
                    logDetails.TableName = entry.EntitySet.Name.ToString();
                    logDetails.Field = columnName.ToString();
                    logDetails.Before = oldValue;
                    logDetails.After = newValue;
                    logDetails.PKValue = entry.CurrentValues[0].ToString();
                    context.AddObject("LogDetails", logDetails);
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. *[ObjectStateEntry.AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.acceptchanges.aspx)* is similar to *[ObjectContext.AcceptAllChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.acceptallchanges.aspx)*, ***except*** that it will *impact only the specific entity*. 


The important point is that by default, the ***SaveChanges*** method calls ***AcceptAllChanges*** method after it has performed the database modifications. Then *AcceptAllChanges* pushes the current values of *every* attached entity into the original values and then changes their *EntityState* to *Unchanged*.

As you can see, your issue coming from the fact that *context.SaveChanges()* is called on the first iteration of your *foreach*, therefore a *AcceptAllChanges()* is invoked by *SaveChanges()* and that make everyone to go into *Unchanged* state.

Answer (score 0):

The [AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.acceptchanges.aspx) method does this by design.
What behavior do you expect?

Comment: Shouldn't entry.AcceptChanges() only accept changes for that particular entity and not the entire context?